# Parse error while combining multiple query statement

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a php code to replace SQL row values. But it is not working as expected

**ERROR : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...... on line 3**

I think i should not use these quotes `" "` right ? But, when i ran this without `" "` got this error

**Error updating comment table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1**

Here is my Code

```
<?php    
include_once("db.php");    
$sql1 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"NK",'NOKIA')";
$sql2 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"SM",'SAMSUNG')";
$sql3 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"A",'APPLE')";
$sql4 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"CH",'CHINAPECE')";
$sql5 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"WO",'WORLDCLASS')";
if (mysql_query($sql1 && $sql2 && $sql3 && $sql4 && $sql5))
  {
  echo "Replaced.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error in replacing: " . mysql_error();
  }
?>
```

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE (updated php code with sujjestions sugested by Trinimon and beiller)**

**ERROR : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in .... on line 8**

```
<?php    
    include_once("db.php");
    $sql1 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"NK",'NOKIA')";
    $sql2 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"SM",'SAMSUNG')";
    $sql3 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"A",'APPLE')";
    $sql4 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"CH",'CHINAPECE')";
    $sql5 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,"WO",'WORLDCLASS')";
    if (mysql_query($sql1);
        mysql_query($sql2);
        mysql_query($sql3);
        mysql_query($sql4);
        mysql_query($sql5);)
  {
      echo "Replaced.";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Error in replacing: " . mysql_error();
      }
    ?>
```

**ERROR : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in .... on line 8**

Comment: Quotes, quotes, quotes. A basic syntax highlighter will catch this for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Comment: I misunderstood the question, my answer is deleted now. Look at the other one, he's right. Just remember that '\' is an escape character for these kinda of things. If you need to actually use '|' you should use '\\' which will result in only one backslash.

Comment: @JohnConde even the SO catches it.

Comment: It is localized but this question can be improved.

Comment: @Starx And what would be the use of that?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽, Such mistakes are very abundant, if it can be addressed in more than one way, isn't that something good?

Comment: @Starx I disagree. Parse error questions are not helpful, except for the one posting the question. The goal of Stackoverflow questions is to help future visitors.

Comment: @Starx No I wouldn't call this question something good no

Comment: @Jocelyn, Look at your right side, I know what you mean. So many questions like this, but parse error are also error in programming So I believe it is a valid question.

Comment: @starx thanks a ton for giving importance to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to unescaped quotes. Use Single Quotes to define the values in a query string. It is less confusing that way.

Also there is a problem with the statements. Since you are combining statements they have to terminated using delimeter `;`

```
$sql = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,'NK','NOKIA');";
$sql .= "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,'SM','SAMSUNG');";
$sql .= "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,'A','APPLE');";
$sql .= "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,'CH','CHINAPECE');";
$sql .= "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,'WO','WORLDCLASS');";
```

And query like this:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

#### **NOTE:** Please dont use MYSQL_* API Functions they are deprecated

Comment: already tried this bro. didn't work.

Comment: @user2373405, Try again. I missed another problem

Comment: not woked bro, same error again >  
 
thanks for your time. but got an error > Error updating comment table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: @user2373405, What is c2

Comment: it is my column name.

Comment: @user2373405, I am changed my answer. Please try that and provide me the output of `echo $sql;`

Comment: thank you bro! solved :) +one and right answer for you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 mysql_query($sql1 && $sql2 && $sql3 && $sql4 && $sql5);
```

This is incorrect. One mysql_query per $sql.

```
mysql_query($sql1);
mysql_query($sql2);
mysql_query($sql3);
mysql_query($sql4);
mysql_query($sql5);
```

As your error message shows $sql1 && $sql2 == TRUE which turns into "1" which is an invalid query.

Comment: when i did this. got this error > `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ........ on line 8`   it is exatly the line it starts `mysql_query($sql1);`

Comment: bro i have updated my question, please check it ones

Comment: thanks a lot bro. bro i have updated my question, please check it ones.. still facing a error

Comment: +1 up for you bro :) thank you!!

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot a semi-colon at the first line. Haha no correct answer for me :(

Comment: @Pyrech  said this before than you :) check his answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use this

```
$sql1 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,\"NK\",'NOKIA')";
$sql2 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,\"SM\",'SAMSUNG')";
$sql3 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,\"A\",'APPLE')";
$sql4 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,\"CH\",'CHINAPECE')";
$sql5 = "update table1 set marks = replace(c2,\"WO\",'WORLDCLASS')";
```

Se [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php) too.

**p.s.**: in addition I'm not so sure about this command:

```
if (mysql_query($sql1 && $sql2 && $sql3 && $sql4 && $sql5))
```

Check out [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (its deprecated and  says "*multiple queries are not supported*"). I think you should use ...

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
...
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your time. but got an error >> Error updating comment table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: I was editing while you added the comment :) please see updates ...

Comment: thank you bro. but still facing an error. have updated my question. check it ones

Comment: +1 up for you bro :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_query($sql1);
        mysql_query($sql2);
        mysql_query($sql3);
        mysql_query($sql4);
        mysql_query($sql5);)
```

is wrong. You should use a logical operator between each statement like && (AND), || (OR)

Comment: thank you but previously I'm using the same. facing error at that time too.. will retrieve my changes back and will try again. thanks

Comment: +1 up for you bro :) thank you!!