# check/uncheck check boxes using onclick

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I don't know why I'm unable to toggle my checkbox with the code mentioned below. But the same code was working fine in another project. But, when I try to implement it in another CodeIgniter project, it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
 <form action=""  method="post" onSubmit="return checkTheBox() " name="checkboxform">';
```

**Onclick event in a href**

```
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void();' onClick='javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', true);'><b>Check All</b></a> | 
     <a href='javascript:void();' onClick='javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', false);'><b>UnCheck All</b></a></td>";
```

**Checkbox**

```
   echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkid[]' value=''</td>";
```

**Javascript**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
   {
   var checkboxes = new Array();
   checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox') {
           checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
          }
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see some problems with your code

- `input` tag is not closed, missing `>`, should be

  ```
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkid[]' value=''></td>
  ```
- The `onclick` attribute and the javascript string in the `a` elements are all enclosed in single quotes `'`

  ```
  onClick='javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', true);'
  ```

  For the browser the `onclick` attribute value is `'javascript:checkAll('` and `checkboxform', true);'` is just garbage, it doesn't understand.

  This should be something like

  ```
  onClick="javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', true);"
  ```

  and in PHP this would be

  ```
  echo "... onClick=\"javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', true);\" ..."
  ```
- `href='javascript:void();` should be `href="javascript:void(0);`

When you fix these errors, it works as expected. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU2PV/1/)

Comment: Btw you (I mean the OP) could cleanup all these obsolete `javascript:` and `language=text/javascript` things. It makes the code less readable for no good reason.

Comment: at Olaf               (actually i am echoing the html elements sir like this) echo "<td><a href='javascript:void();' onClick='javascript:checkAll();'><b>Check All</b></a> | 
         <a href='javascript:void();' onClick='javascript:checkAll('checkboxform', false);'><b>UnCheck All</b></a></td>";

Comment: @shankar Yes, but it doesn't matter, how you create the attributes. The important part is, you use the same quotes `'` for enclosing the attribute value and the Javascript string. This confuses the browser, since it doesn't know where the attribute value *really* ends. See also updated answer.

Comment: @Olaf,,,,,,fine,,,,so i will change the javascript attribute from ' to ",,like onClick='javascript:checkAll("checkboxform", false);',,,when i did,it says error

Comment: but now,,when i changed all my php to normal html tags and single quotes to double quotes for java script value;;its working fine,,,,

Comment: this is a small issue,but i cant fix it up,when i am echoing with php single tag the whole html elements

Comment: @shankar Maybe this question helps understand the issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/7999148/1741542

Comment: anyow,,thx a lot OLAF for ur post and made me think.....nd do u know any website to learn codeigniter for all form elements and how to call javascript libraries in codeigniter

Comment: @shankar I learned using Codeigniter from the documentation at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter and http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: alright,,,,i have swapped my double quotes and single quotes,,,,now i understood,,,,thx Olaf