# Using ' and " in PHP String

Tags: php, string

How can I use a `'` and a `"` in a php string? 
I can't use one of them because I have used both in my website code and I think it's better and easier if I make a class for the website that than just echo everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all you can escape then `"this is \" and ' in a string"`

or you can use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead

```
$string = <<<STR
this is a "string" with 'signs' and {$some_var} if needed
STR;
```

Note this rules though:
1. The choose of `STR` was arbitrary and you can use any phrase you would like (no spaces).
2. The row with the `STR;` must contain NOTHING but it (not even spaces after)