# How do I add a class name to an HTML <li> nested in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently doing an exercise on foreach loops in PHP and I wanted to use bootstrap and add a class to my list item in my PHP.

```
<?php
$groceries = array("eggs", "milk", "bread", "apples", "bananas", "fruit rollups", "steak", "kale", "pasta", "flour", "sugar", "vanilla");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Array Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My Grocery List</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <?php
            foreach ($groceries as $purchase) {
            echo "<li class="list-group-item">" . $purchase . "</li>";
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following :

```
echo "<li class="list-group-item">" . $purchase . "</li>";
```

By :

```
echo '<li class="list-group-item">' . $purchase . "</li>";
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it, I forgot that I could use single or double quotes to differentiate.