# How to combine "LIKE" with "IN" in a MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, sql-like

I have this code to search for a matching result in a MYSQL database:

```
$where[] = 'p.id IN (
    SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
      FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
     WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
       AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
       AND ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . ' = adcfvc.field_value
)';
```

I want to change the above search query from selecting exact match using the equal sign "=" operator to selecting any matching result using the "LIKE" operator with two wildcards "%adcfvc.field_value%".

In other words: the current role of the above code is that when the user search for "Hello my people" the query will search for the exact word.
However, I want the user to be able to search using the word "Hello" or "people" only, and he get all results including "Hello my people".

Knowing that I cannot change any of the database structure in anyway, just modify the above code.

The entire code file called "query.php" is available at:
http://123dizajn.com/boltours/stackex/query.txt
I couldn't paste the whole code here as it exceeded body limits, and it was renamed to query.txt just to be viewable.

---

### Trial#1

So, I tried to just replace (at the very end of the code):

```
= adcfvc.field_value
```

With:

```
LIKE %adcfvc.field_value%
```

with no success :(

---

### Trial#2

I tried to reverse the lookup order and use multiple logical operators:-

```
$where[] = 'p.id IN (
    SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
      FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
     WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
       AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
       AND
         (adcfvc.field_value > ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . '
         OR adcfvc.field_value < ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . '
         OR adcfvc.field_value = ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . ')
)';
```

But this returns all items, not the searched ones!

---

### Trial#3

I also tried to reverse and use the `LIKE %...%`:-

```
$where[] = 'p.id IN (
    SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
      FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
     WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
       AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
       AND adcfvc.field_value LIKE %' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . '%
)';
```

But this returns an error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%'apartment'%) GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY `ap`.`price` DESC LIMIT 0,
>   20' at line 12 SQL=SELECT p.*, p.id AS id, p.title AS title,
>   p.street_num, p.street, p.description as description,ap.price, pr.name
>   as priceName,usr.id as advert_user_id,countries.title as
>   country_name,states.title as state_name,date_format(p.created,
>   '%Y-%m-%d') as fcreated,c.title as category_title, c.id as category_id
>   FROM `b1yvu_koparent` AS `p` LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_advert_prices`
>   AS `ap` ON ap.advertId = p.id AND ap.advertDateRangeGroupId = 0 AND
>   ap.priceId = p.priceUnitId LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_prices` AS `pr`
>   ON pr.id = p.priceUnitId LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_advertmid` AS `pm`
>   ON pm.advert_id = p.id LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_usermid` AS `am` ON
>   am.advert_id = p.id LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_users` AS `usr` ON
>   usr.id = am.user_id LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_categories` AS `c` ON
>   c.id = pm.cat_id LEFT JOIN
>   `b1yvu_koparent_advert_specific_fields_values` AS `asfv` ON
>   asfv.advert_id = p.id LEFT JOIN `b1yvu_koparent_countries` AS
>   `countries` ON countries.id = p.country LEFT JOIN
>   `b1yvu_koparent_states` AS `states` ON states.id = p.locstate WHERE
>   p.published = 1 AND p.approved = 1 AND c.published = 1 AND
>   (p.publish_up = '0000-00-00' OR p.publish_up <= '2015-09-05') AND
>   (p.publish_down = '0000-00-00' OR p.publish_down >= '2015-09-05') AND
>   (c.publish_up = '0000-00-00' OR c.publish_up <= '2015-09-05') AND
>   (c.publish_down = '0000-00-00' OR c.publish_down >= '2015-09-05') AND
>   p.access IN (1,9) AND c.access IN (1,9) AND c.language IN
>   ('en-GB','*') AND p.language IN ('en-GB','*') AND p.id IN (SELECT
>   adcfvc.advert_id FROM b1yvu_koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS
>   adcfvc WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id AND adcfvc.field_name =
>   't4_cust_AdvertTitleEN' AND adcfvc.field_value LIKE %'apartment'%)
>   GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY `ap`.`price` DESC LIMIT 0, 20

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Think you've got that backwards, try `adcfvc.field_value LIKE "%' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . '%"`

Comment: have you tried to add single quotes around the string? LIKE '%adcfvc.field_value%' You'll have to escape the single quotes in the php code.

Comment: @swornabsent Well, the page was successfully loaded, but the suggested query did not function at all.

Comment: @mk97 I do not know how to "escape the single quotes in the php code". Would you please tell me what to try directly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php

Comment: @mk97 Wow, that a long article to study! Can you please just tell me what to replace directly? Thank you.

Comment: It would really be great to show what you are getting (an error or the wrong results). Also to use `$query->dump()` to show the generated query which you can then test directly.

Comment: Also I'm really not getting this `$where[] `  What is that doing in the middle of a JDatabaseQuery?  You don't need to worry about escaping if you use `quote()` and `quoteName()` correctly.

Comment: `'%'apartment'%`  is one reason why you are having a problem.  You have included the single quotes in the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RLIKE` instead of the approached `LIKE` was the most simple and direct solution for my question.

Final full query:-

```
$where[] = 'p.id IN (
    SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
      FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
     WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
       AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
       AND adcfvc.field_value RLIKE ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . '
)';
```

This made the results return all items that their name **included** the searched value.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Your suggestion to __reverse logic lookup__ was very helpful to solve this question; yet being fresh border couldn't allow me to vote it up.

Comment: @mk97 @Elin Your answers and comments also helped me very well. But you couldn't think of `RLIKE` though ;p - Thanks.

Comment: @Elin Have you seen my resolution? It resolved the problem without any further modifications.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's `quote` not `Quote`. 
Second you should use `quoteName()` for names of fields.
Third there's no reason to stop using the API just because you have a subquery.
Also your code is very confusing about which is the field name and which is the value.  I assume that `$sf_value` represents the value that you are trying to match and `adcfvc.field`  is the name of the field that stores the data you are trying to match.

Replace

```
 AND ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . ' = adcfvc.field_value
```

with

```
 AND ' .  $db->quoteName( 'adcfvc.field_value' ) . ' LIKE  ' .  $db->quote('%' . JString::strtolower($sf_value) . '%')
```

I'm not sure why you are using JString there but if you feel it's necessary then fine.

Here is your subquery

```
SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
  FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
 WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
   AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
   AND ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($sf_value)) . ' = adcfvc.field_value
```

So you since you have `$db` already.

```
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true); 
// Assuming p.id is an integer
$subquery->where($db->quoteName(adcfvc.advert_id) = p.id)
//Assuming $sf_key is an integer
->where($db->quoteName(adcfvc.field_name) . ' = ' . $sf_key)
->where($db->quoteName(adcfvc.field_value) . ' LIKE ' 
    .   $db->Quote('%'. JString::strtolower($sf_value) . '%')) ;
```

Then in the top level query, which you have just shown us one part of, something like

```
$query->where('p.id IN (' . $subquery . ')' );
```

Comment: This piece of code is part of a very big component working on Joomla 3.4. However, you can check the output at 123dizajn.com/boltours/en/contact and use the search field on the top left. To understand what I mean, search for "Katarina 1 Apartments A2" and you will get a result, but if you search for only "Katarina" you will not get any results! Although your assumption is right, I also tried your suggestion but it gives a blank page! Finally, I know this piece of code I posted is bit confusing. Let me know what you think, then I'll update it and let you check again. Help appreciated.

Comment: Turn error reporting to development.  Why don't you just make a finder plugin?   Add `echo $query->dump();` after you finish building the query.  Are you positive that your query works in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Also please update the question to show your whole query starting with defining `$db`.

Comment: You should read this link about how to do subqueries with the Joomla api http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1/method-for-creating-a-subquery-using-jdatabase

Comment: I did not try to execute the same code in phpMyAdmin, but it works very fine on the functionality side, my problem is that it gives exact match, and I want a wildcard match "%...%". I've added a link for the entire file as requested. Help appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question with my trials and their returns, please check if the returned ones can be fixed.

Comment: If it isnt returnig what you expect it is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the like logic on your column using `concat`

```
SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
AND 'Hello my people'  like concat('%',adcfvc.field_value,'%')
order by adcfvc.field_value like '%Hello my people%' desc
```

This will match (Hello my people,Hello,my and people) added order by to show  complete match first

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/538b0/1)

Another way if you can break you text by words you can use or conditions to match with `field_value`

```
SELECT adcfvc.advert_id
FROM #__koparent_advert_specific_fields_values AS adcfvc
WHERE adcfvc.advert_id = p.id
AND adcfvc.field_name = ' . $db->Quote($sf_key) . '
AND  (
  adcfvc.field_value like '%Hello my people%'
  or adcfvc.field_value like '%Hello%'
  or adcfvc.field_value like '%my%'
  or adcfvc.field_value like '%people%'
)
order by adcfvc.field_value like '%Hello my people%' desc
```

[`DEMO 2`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/538b0/2)

Comment: Please note that I only mentioned "Hello my people" as an example. I believe your solution might work if you can make it generic using only the give code (i.e. without any fixed text).

Comment: @MHDSKY yes i have used this phrase "Hello my people" for example it can be anything value of php var `$sf_value`

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I tried to replace `'%Hello my people%'` with `'%$sf_value%'` with no success, the page loaded empty white :(  If possible, please post the exact code to try, maybe I mis replaced it.

Comment: try something like `AND ' . $db->Quote('%'.JString::strtolower($sf_value).'%') . '  LIKE ....` you are not manipulating variables correctly in your query

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Basically the original code I posted works fine, but only returns exact matches as perviously mentioned. I understand that you might want to suggest a better improved structure, totally welcome. Can you please edit your answer and tell me what to replace exactly? This will be much easier for me to understand and apply.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I managed to try the suggested `AND ' . $db->Quote('%'.JString::strtolower($sf_value).'%') . ' LIKE ....`. Although the page loads, the search returns nothing at all! - Any more suggestions please?

Comment: @MHDSKY can you create a sample fiddle demo with sample data set ? and also echo your generated query see whats query is generated it matches with the suggested one ? or not

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Unfortunately, I am not familiar with SQLFIDDLE, in addition being this piece of code part of a very big component working on Joomla 3.4. However, you can check the output at http://www.123dizajn.com/boltours/en/contact and use the search field on the top left. To understand what I mean, search for "Katarina 1 Apartments A2" and you will get a result, but if you search for only "Katarina" you will not get any results! Finally, I know this piece of code I posted controls the situation, let me know what you think, then I'll update it and let you check again. Help appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestions as trials and their returns, please check if the returned ones can be fixed. Also it worth mentioning that I second your opinion to _reverse the like logic_ as I feel it is more closer to be resolved that way.