# Adding onclick and window.location.href

Tags: php, html

I'm sending a html email from php. The body is wrapped in double quotes (`"`). How do I add a button onclick event and a link within the double quotes?

```
$body = "<BODY>
    <button type='button' onclick='window.location.href='www.example.com/page.html?id=".$id."''>
</BODY>";
```

How do I do `onclick='window.location.href='''`

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to [escape quotes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7999163/622391).

Comment: Many email service providers remove javascript code from the email source. I would recommend you to use <a></a> links instead of button to archive this.
To give a look of button, create an image and link you page on that image. Like
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/page.htm"><img src='http://www.yoursite.com/button.jpg'></a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

Use slash

```
$body = "<BODY>
     <button type='button' onclick=\"window.location.href='www.example.com/page.html?id=".$id."'\">
</BODY>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) which means you don't have to worry about escaping double quotes **or** single quotes.

```
$body = <<<EOT
<body>
  <button type="button"
          onclick="window.location.href='www.example.com/page.html?id={$id}'">
    click me
  </button>
</body>";
EOT;
```

Or you can skip writing [obtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) altogether and your issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to escaping double quotes with `\` in the string you can just use a separate string to store your substring. ie.

```
$href = '"www.example.com/page.html?id='.$id.'"';
$body = "<BODY>
    <button type='button' onclick='window.location.href=".$href."'>
</BODY>";
```

Answer (score 0):

write a onclick function an move your location using that function.

```
<html>
<script>
function locations(){
    //var id=20; get the value of id and save in id(getElementById or jquery) 
window.location.href='www.example.com/page.html?id='+id;
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="locations()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this is storing quotes in variables

```php
<?php
$quotes-dbl = '"';$quotes-sgl "'";
echo $quotes-dbl."text".$quotes-dbl;
```