# Create Database in utf8 with a variable

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I tried to create a database in utf8 in order to collect some informations in arabic and I made 2 php documents, but some errors occur. It displays :

```
 *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"'(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\...\Setup.php on line 13

(Line 13 is this line : " $resultat=mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$base "CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $id ); "
```

**First php document : Parametres.php**

```
  $host="localhost"; 
  $user="user";
  $pass="pass";
  $base="Databasename";
```

**Second php document :**

```
  include("Parametres.php");<br>
  $id=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);<br>
  $resultat=mysql_query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ".$base,$id);<br>
  $resultat=mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$base "CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $id );<br>
```

...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You are missing the string concatenation operator `.`. A space character inside the CHARACTER SET string is also missing

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the single quote [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php),Change your code as below

```
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$base." DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
mysql_query($sql, $id );
```

Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/create_mysql_database_using_php.htm) for create database using php mysql