# Quote escape issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the below code to add an attribute to my gravity forms form tag. But there seems to be a problem with the "toLocaleString('en-US')" part. I assume this is a quote issue? As there's single quotes being used inside single quotes.... How can I fix this?

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'gform_form_tag', 'form_tag', 10, 2 );
function form_tag( $form_tag, $form ) {
    if ( $form['id'] != 1 ) {
        return $form_tag;
    }
    $form_tag = str_ireplace( "<form ", "<form oninput='loanval.value=parseInt(loan.value, 10).toLocaleString('en-US'); periodval.value=period.value;' ", $form_tag );
    return $form_tag;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash as such

```
"From time to \"time\"";
```

Backslashes are used in PHP to escape special characters within quotes. As PHP does not distinguish between strings and characters, you could also use this

```
'From time to "time"';
```

It has been answered before, here: 
[Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)