# Create clicable hyperlink in table using php with sql (ASC/DESC)

Tags: php

I'm sorry if this is unclear or difficult to understand, but explaining what I am attempting to do isn't that easy over text.
In the HTML code like this entry works:

```
<th><a href="members.php?id=<?php echo 'name';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">Name</a></th>
<td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
```

but in PHP I can not advise:

```
echo "<th><a href="members.php?id=<?php echo 'name';?>&action=<?php echo $action;?>">Name</a></th>";
echo "<td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>";

"id" has value /name, lastname, city, district/ 
"action" has value /ASC, DESC/
```

Complete table for clarity I not want to indicate.
Can you help me?

Now I have:

```
echo "<th><a href=\"members.php?id=<?php echo 'name';?\>&action=<?php echo $action;?\>\">Name</a></th>";
echo "<td><?php echo '".$row['name']."';?\></td>";
```

expected result in URL is:

```
.../members.php?id=name&action=ASC
```

but my is:

```
.../members.php?id=<?php%20echo%20%27name%27;?\>&action=<?php%20echo%20;?\>
```

can you anybody help me?

Edit 2

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo '<th><a href="members.php?id='.$row['name'].'&action=' . $action . '">Name</a></th>';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<td> ' . $row['name'] . '</td>';

Undefined variable: 'row'
```

can you help me?

Comment: You need to escape your quotation marks. Duplicate of: [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot self advise with this problem.
Have you any different idea, or solving? Please.

Comment: As I've already said: Escape quotation marks: `echo "<th><a href=\"..` Use the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When you echoes that is already between `<?php` tags.

```
<?php
echo '<th><a href="members.php?id='.$row['name'].'&action=' . $action . '">Name</a></th>';
echo '<td> ' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
?>
```

But I suggest you to use it as a template, not from PHP (this is html code)

```
<th><a href="members.php?id=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>&action=<?php echo $action; ?>">Name</a></th>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>;
```

Comment: The first part works <th>.....
But second <td> no
Result by clicking on header is:

    `Trying to get property of non-object in`

I have: 
`$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: Your connection to the server, or your query has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 100% working..

```
echo '<th><a href="members.php?id='$name'&action='$action"'>Name</a></th>';
echo '<td>'$row["name"]'</td>';
```

Comment: I am sorry, no working, because `unexpected $name` is variable `name/lastname/city/district`