# Adding a jQuery code to a PHP string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add a jQuery code to a PHP string

Here is the PHP code

```
    $my_code ='
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#my_form").on("submit", function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#myButton").attr("disabled", ""); 
            $("#my-output").html(‘<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">My message</div>’);
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: "# my-output ",
            success:  afterSuccess
            });
        });
    });

function afterSuccess()
{   

    $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");

}
</script>
    ‘;
```

Issue I’m having in this code line

```
$("#my-output").html(‘<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">My message</div>’);
```

I even try change the single quote to double quotes and when I do code stopped working. It works fine if I don’t have a div inside above code line. 
Ex:

```
$("#my-output").html(“My message”);
```

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: Why not create a separate .js file with that code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single quotes inside the string, however you will need to `\'` [escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php):

```
'$("#my-output").html(\'<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">My message</div>\');'
```

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Heredoc Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to avoid quote issues.