# Php file not reading css classname

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code.

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <td class="tablehead">Name
    </td>       
    <td class="tablehead">Email
    </td>
    <td class="tablehead">Comment
    </td>
</tr>";
```

and corresponding code in linked css file to turn content of tablehead class white against coloured background. Running this on the browser is returning this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'tablehead' (T_STRING),
>   expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 110. (line
>   110 is line 3 of this code pasted here.)

Why? What do I do?

Comment: Escape the quotation marks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<table>
<tr>
    <td class="tablehead">Name
    </td>       
    <td class="tablehead">Email
    </td>
    <td class="tablehead">Comment
    </td>
</tr>';
```

use ' instead "