# I want to take the first character of use LEFT on laravel `

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Maybe anyone can help me?

This is my controller.

```
$takegolongan = Pekerjaan::select ('LEFT('golongan_jabatan', 1)')->where('cno', '00001222')->get();

echo $takegolongan;
```

This is the data that I want to take :

[image]

output on the screen (error):

[image]

Comment: Just escape the apostrophe(for the life of me I can't remember what `'` is called in english.): `$takegolongan = Pekerjaan::select ('LEFT(\'golongan_jabatan\', 1)')->where('cno', '00001222')->get();
`. Other than that your query seems correct.

Comment: Same thing. Escape the apostrophe. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php). And get a decent IDE, it will warn you about such small issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add single quote inside the double quote or you should use backslash, I can only see the issue of quotes. Like:

```
    $takegolongan = Pekerjaan::select ("LEFT('golongan_jabatan', 1)")->where('cno', '00001222')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB::raw() like this:

```
use DB;

$takegolongan = Pekerjaan::select(DB::raw('LEFT(`golongan_jabatan`, 1)'))
    ->where('cno', '00001222')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You changed the query @Jin.C so it will no longer work. You've changed the apostrophe string delimiters around golongan_jabatan for backtick delimiters which is used to denote a schema name.