# How to delete object from arrayObject in php?

Tags: php, arrays, object, unset

I want delete object from arrayObject in php, but in deleteComputer method show this error: "Warning: Illegal offset type", help me pls, Im starting with php :)

i've:

```
       class ControllerList {

            private $computers;

            function __construct() {
                $this->computers= new ArrayObject();

            }

         public function addComputer($computer) {
             $this->computers->append($computer);
         }

         public function deleteComputer($computerNumber) {
             foreach ($this->computers as $value) {
                 if($value->getNumber() == computerNumber){
                    unset($this->computers[$value]);
                    echo 'Delete!!';
                 } else {
                    echo 'Don't delete!!';
                 }
               }
         }

        }
```

Main file:/

```
         $list = new ControllerList();

         $computer1 = new Computer();
         $computer1->setNumber(001);
         $computer1->setColor("Black");

         $computer2 = new Computer();
         $computer2->setNumber(002);
         $computer2->setColor("White");

         $list->addComputer($computer1);
         $list->addComputer($computer2);

         $list->deleteComputer(001);  --> error method
```

Comment: `computerNumber` should be `$computerNumber`

Answer (score 2):

`$value` is an object, not an array index. You need to add the array index to the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($this->computers as $i => $value) {
    if($value->getNumber() == $computerNumber){
        unset($this->computers[$i]);
        echo 'Delete!!';
    } else {
        echo 'Don't delete!!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As with Barmar's solution, I would address your escaping issue here.

```
 echo 'Don't delete!!';
```

to

```
echo "Don't delete!!";
```

or

```
echo 'Don\'t delete!!';
```

Additional information on escaping strings can be found here:
[Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)