# str_replace and using extra "

Tags: php, str-replace

Hello I am using the str_replace but in the comparity I am using extra " thus it is not working. how can I use extra " inside the str_replace

```
$errorAlerts = str_replace("Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.", "{$record['c_pw']}", $errorsAndAlerts);
```

Thanks for your input

Comment: `str_replace('Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.', "{$record['c_pw']}", $errorsAndAlerts);` ?

Comment: use surrounding single quotes instead of double quotes, or [escape your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Comment: Go learn some basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either escape

`$errorAlerts = str_replace("Password found in list of \"most common passwords\", please choose a more secure password.", $record['c_pw'], $errorsAndAlerts);`

or use single quotes

`$errorAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.', $record['c_pw'], $errorsAndAlerts);`

Comment: Hi yea, While using either the \ or the single quotes I do not get errors but the str_replace does not work aka the comparison does not work. I am using a cms and this is the error it is giving out, but I have a multilingual website thus I wanted to replace it with the correct language but the comparison does not work. if you have any input as to why I would be grateful.

Comment: @EmmaLinnery: Btw you have two different variables mentioned in the code: `$errorAlerts` and `$errorsAndAlerts`. Could it be that you are saving the replaced text to the wrong variable?

Comment: thank you sorry,

$errorsAlerts = str_replace("Password found in list of \"most common passwords\", please choose a more secure password.", "ding dong", $errorsAlerts);

It doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Us single quotes around a double quoted literal

```
$errorAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.', 
                            $record['c_pw'], 
                            $errorsAndAlerts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods here

Use `\` to escape double quotes

```
$errorAlerts = str_replace("Password found in list of \"most common passwords\", please choose a more secure password.", {$record['c_pw']}, $errorsAndAlerts);
```

Or you can use singe quotes.

```
$errorAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.', {$record['c_pw']}, $errorsAndAlerts);
```

> To specify a literal double quote, escape it with a backslash ().

Here is a good reference from php page how to use single and double quotes. Check out [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)