# How to echo multiple div?

Tags: php, html, css, echo, division

I want to echo this html code but unable to this 

code:

```
<div class="cbp-item <?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['catName'] ) ); ?>">
            <div class="cbp-caption">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img src="gallery/<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['gFILE_NAME'] ) ); ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <h4>by <?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['picCourtesy'] ) ); ?></h4>
                            <a href="gallery/<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['gFILE_NAME'] ) ); ?>" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonRight" data-title="by <?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['picCourtesy'] ) ); ?>">view larger</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

how can i echo this, like `<?php echo '<div>' hellow '</div>'; ?>`

Comment: You do: `<?php echo '<div>hellow</div>'; ?>`. With a dot you can concatenate multiple strings: `<?php echo '<div>'.'hellow'.'</div>'; ?>`. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php

Comment: these multiple division making me crazy :( @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Is this in a loop? Where is `$row` being set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine two strings together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<div class="cbp-item '.$catName.' ">
            <div class="cbp-caption">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img src="gallery/'.$gFILE_NAME.'" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <h4>by '.$picCourtesy.'</h4>
                            <a href="gallery/'.$gFILE_NAME.'" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonRight" data-title="by '.$picCourtesy.'">view larger</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
```

you dont need to use `<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['catName'] ) ); ?>` if you are trying to echo the div.

Answer (score 1):

You do: `<?php echo '<div>Hello</div>'; ?>`

Exemple:

```html
<?php 
echo '<p dir=rtl id="textmsg" style="color: '.$donnees['color'].';">'.$donnees['text'].'</p>';
?>
```