# send huge html mail by phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
    //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $url="localhost/activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion";
            define('URL',"$url");
            $body="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">
    /* FONTS */
    @media screen {
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Lato';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
        }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Lato';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qdgUG4U09HnJwhYI-uK18wLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
        }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Lato';
          font-style: italic;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('Lato Italic'), local('Lato-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/RYyZNoeFgb0l7W3Vu1aSWOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff');
        }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Lato';
          font-style: italic;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: local('Lato Bold Italic'), local('Lato-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/HkF_qI1x_noxlxhrhMQYELO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
        }
    }

    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
    body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }

    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width:600px){
        h1 {
            font-size: 32px !important;
            line-height: 32px !important;
        }
    }

    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    We are thrilled to have you here! Get ready to dive into your new account.
</div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFA73B" align="center">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 10px 40px 10px;">
                        <a href="localhost" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="Logo" src="logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFA73B" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" >
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px; border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; color: #111111; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 4px; line-height: 48px;">
                      <h1 style="font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0;">Welcome!</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" >
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                  <p style="margin: 0;">We are excited to have you get started. First, you need to confirm your account. Just press the button below.</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 30px 60px 30px;">
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#FFA73B"><a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion' target="_blank" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #FFA73B; display: inline-block;">Confirm Account</a></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                  <p style="margin: 0;">"If that does not work, copy and paste the following link in your browser:"</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                    <p style="margin: 0;"><a href='URL' target="_blank" style="color: #FFA73B;">URL</a></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                  <p style="margin: 0;">If you have any questions, just reply to this email—we are always happy to help out.</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 0px 30px 40px 30px; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                  <p style="margin: 0;">Cheers,<br>The Edutheon Team</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="center" style="padding: 30px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" >
            <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFECD1" align="center" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;" >
                    <h2 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #111111; margin: 0;">Need more help?</h2>
                    <p style="margin: 0;"><a href="contact.php" target="_blank" style="color: #FFA73B;">We&rsquo;re here, ready to talk</a></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>"";
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->isHTML(True)
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();
```

how to do I send this email with phpmailer whenever i try to send it always return an error and i cannot use `get_file_contents()` because it contains variables dependent on variables please answer Thanks I think this problem arises due to "/' used in the html Using this code on xampp server and the it working on text email and not on the html plz help i need to complete my project.

Comment: whats the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using double quotation marks the define the `$body` variable, then using them throughout the value you set it to, causing the string reading to break.

I think [reading this answer would help you a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Literally replacing all `"` with `\"` inside the string should work (though if you have any legitimate uses of variables inside which I missed, I did not see them).  Here would be the corrected code:

```
 $body = <!DOCTYPE html>
          html>
          <head>
          <title></title>
          <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />
          <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
          <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" />
          <style type=\"text/css\">
/* FONTS */
@media screen {
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qdgUG4U09HnJwhYI-uK18wLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Lato Italic'), local('Lato-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/RYyZNoeFgb0l7W3Vu1aSWOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff');
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: local('Lato Bold Italic'), local('Lato-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/HkF_qI1x_noxlxhrhMQYELO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
    }
}

/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */
img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

/* MOBILE STYLES */
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    h1 {
        font-size: 32px !important;
        line-height: 32px !important;
    }
}

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
div[style*=\"margin: 16px 0;\"] { margin: 0 !important; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body style=\"background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;\">
 <div style=\"display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;\">
   We are thrilled to have you here! Get ready to dive into your new account.
 </div>

 <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#FFA73B\" align=\"center\">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\">
        <tr>
        <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" width=\"600\">
        <![endif]-->
        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" style=\"max-width: 600px;\" >
            <tr>
                <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" style=\"padding: 40px 10px 40px 10px;\">
                    <a href=\"localhost\" target=\"_blank\">
                        <img alt=\"Logo\" src=\"logo.png\">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#FFA73B\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;\">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\">
        <tr>
        <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" width=\"600\">
        <![endif]-->
        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" style=\"max-width: 600px;\" >
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" style=\"padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px; border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; color: #111111; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 4px; line-height: 48px;\">
                  <h1 style=\"font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0;\">Welcome!</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#f4f4f4\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;\">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\">
        <tr>
        <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" width=\"600\">
        <![endif]-->
        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" style=\"max-width: 600px;\" >
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
              <p style=\"margin: 0;\">We are excited to have you get started. First, you need to confirm your account. Just press the button below.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\">
              <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 20px 30px 60px 30px;\">
                    <table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
                      <tr>
                          <td align=\"center\" style=\"border-radius: 3px;\" bgcolor=\"#FFA73B\"><a href='\".DIR.\"activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion' target=\"_blank\" style=\"font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #FFA73B; display: inline-block;\">Confirm Account</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
              <p style=\"margin: 0;\">\"If that does not work, copy and paste the following link in your browser:\"</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
                <p style=\"margin: 0;\"><a href='URL' target=\"_blank\" style=\"color: #FFA73B;\">URL</a></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
              <p style=\"margin: 0;\">If you have any questions, just reply to this email—we are always happy to help out.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 0px 30px 40px 30px; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
              <p style=\"margin: 0;\">Cheers,<br>The Edutheon Team</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor=\"#f4f4f4\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 30px 10px 0px 10px;\">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\">
        <tr>
        <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\" width=\"600\">
        <![endif]-->
        <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" style=\"max-width: 600px;\" >
        <tr>
              <td bgcolor=\"#FFECD1\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;\" >
                <h2 style=\"font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; color: #111111; margin: 0;\">Need more help?</h2>
                <p style=\"margin: 0;\"><a href=\"contact.php\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color: #FFA73B;\">We&rsquo;re here, ready to talk</a></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: heredoc is probably a better approach than all that escaping

Comment: I'd do a `file_get_contents` on an external source and `str_replace` the variables, but this person sounds like they're so new to PHP that this seemed a more appropriate stepping stone.

Comment: just a pain in the arse having to worry about which quotes you can and ant use\ escape where they is a way to deal with them... its php there's 1ll way 10 ways to do anything :-)

Comment: can you please delete this answer cause the question with -3 votes dooesnt looks nice on my profile!!

Comment: cause stackoverflow doesnt allows me to delete the question