# $variable output between quotes

Tags: php

I am learning PHP, and I want to output a PHP variable in between single quotes, something like this:

```
 $var1 = 'Text here';
 $var2 = $var1;

 echo $var2;
```

The output of $var2 should be:

```
 'Text here'
```

(including the single quotes).

Does someone know the best way how to do this?

Comment: In addition of Praveen's answer, I suggest the use of escape characters as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just like that add a string. You need to enclose them in a string first.

```
$var1 = "'Text here'"; // Enclose this way.
$var2 = $var1;

echo $var2;
```

In your understanding, using the following code will give you an error.

```
$var = Hello World; // Error
```

In normal ways, a string can be defined by:

```
$var = "Hello World"; // or
$var = 'Hello World';
```

If you need to include quotes, you can also use escape characters. See [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7999148).

```
$var = "Hello \"Real\" World!";
```

And in your case, it could be:

```
$var1 = '\'Text here\'';
```

Another interesting way is:

```
$var1 = 'Text here';
$var2 = "'$var1'";
```