# How to get this code correctly to display title in quotes?

Tags: php

I have this code here which is meant to display the title tag in quotes besides the  code.

```
$item_output .= '<a'. " title=" . " $item->attr_title " . $attributes .'>';
```

Can someone please guide on how to get the title in quotes.
Currently it is displayed as follows:

```
<a title=the tag href="http://url.com">
```

However, it should display as follows:

```
<a title="the tag" href="http://url.com">
```

Please help.

I have tried to remove the Quotes as in tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$item_output .= '<a'. " title=" . " '$item->attr_title '" . $attributes .'>';

$item_output .= '<a'. " title=" . "' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '" . $attributes .'>';

$item_output .= '<a'. " title=" . " . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . " . $attributes .'>';
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php as an option for outputting quotes inside of a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually including quotes in the strings you are outputting. An easy way in this case would be:

```
$item_output .= '<a title="' . $item->attr_title . '" ' . $attributes .'>';
```

Comment: That will also wrap the attributes which is showing the href="http://url.com" also within the title which we do not want.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I didn't realize what `$attributes` was. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (escaping the quotes):

```
$item_output .= '<a title=\"'. $item->attr_title.'\" '.$attributes.'>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and @Aioros but using the same code that you provided stopped displaying the title.

Comment: Hi @Johannes
I am getting the error
    syntax error, unexpected ''" '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: Also when I used your code such as follows:
    $item_output .= '<a title=\"' . $item->attr_title . '"\ ' .$attributes . '>';
Then i am able to get the title details but with the slashes at the end and the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
$item_output .= '<a title="' . $item->attr_title . '" ' . $attributes .'>';
```

Output:

> `<a title="The Title" href="http://url.com">`

[**PHP Fiddle Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/qxk1-n0ib)  <sup>hit "Run" to get the code executed</sup>

Comment: Your code works perfectly in the Demo but it only works on my end when I add the space between title= and the quote i.e. as follows '<a title= "' . $item->attr_title . '" ' . $attributes .'>'; and that also displays the space in the frontend but when I remove the space, it doesn't display the title tag. Any idea of what could be wrong here!

Comment: Do you have the content and the href closing tag `</a>` in your code? because if you check [**this fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/iwi3-x8cg) you'll see the different result..

Comment: Here’s my code
`  if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) )`
`     $item_output .= '<a title="'. $item->attr_title .'"'. $attributes .'>';`
`    else`
` $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';`
` $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;`
` $item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? '</a>' : '</a>';` `$item_output .= $args->after;`
` $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );'`

Comment: I think this line (right after the `if` statement) cannot be rendered because it doesn't have closing tag `$item_output .= '<a title="'. $item->attr_title .'"'. $attributes .'>';`

Comment: try this for testing `$item_output .= '<a title="'. $item->attr_title .'"'. $attributes .'>test</a>';`

Comment: I agree but the second and third line after the `else` statement does take care of that and this is the navigation menu so putting just one text won't help.

Comment: ok. but without content, right? what should appear as rendered link text ?

Comment: Check this [**image**](https://prnt.sc/m5n4ya) .. You see if you "inspect" it, the link is there but it's empty, nothing to display

Comment: Please check the source code for this website [Jenas Carpet Cleaning](https://jenascarpetcleaning.com.au) and search for title=" and you'll notice that currently it shows the title tags for individual navigation items but with a space between the `title` and the actual rendered text.

Comment: I don't have any `title="` followed by a space!, in the source code I mean

Comment: Yes, but If I do not put the space, the code do not display title tag. But it does display the attributes properly with the closing </a> tag. If I out the space everything display perfectly fine except the space as mentioned above.

Comment: Nothing in the code shown in all fiddles could produce such a glitch, it might be something else

Comment: Hmm. Will see what to do. Thanks for all your help @Mi-Creativity.