# Quote from PHP is transformed into &#039 into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, chart.js

I need a specific format that I build in my PHP and which is then sent to my view and the JavaScript (using Symfony, but this is not a Symfony issue).

The problem is specified in the title: the `'` from the string is transformed into my js and I don't want it to be transformed

Here are how it looks like

PHP side

```
        case "01":
            $dynamic_month="['Février ".$previous_year."','Mars ".$previous_year."','Avril ".$previous_year."','Mai ".$previous_year."
            ','Juin ".$previous_year."','Juillet ".$previous_year."','Août ".$previous_year."','Septembre ".$previous_year."','Octobre 
            ".$previous_year."','Novembre ".$previous_year."','Décembre ".$previous_year."','Janvier ".$year."']";
            break;
```

This is building a string with something like `['Month Year','NextMonth Year']` (this is what a var_dump is printing.

But in my JavaScript (chart.js inside a twig view). The `'` are replaced.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                    labels: {{ dynamic_month }},
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Connexion / mois",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        data: connectedByMonth,
                    }]
                },

                // Configuration options go here
                options: {}
            });
```

The issue is on the line

`labels: {{ dynamic_month }}`

this is replaced once compiled by this

`labels: [&#039;Février 2018&#039;,&#039;Mars 2018&#039;, et caetera et caetera`

Comment: How is your JSON returned from your PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this escaping quotes: [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

if that doesnt work, you could always do a str.replace after the fact and properly convert it back

Comment: If I use `\'` then I get `\&#039;` so I guess it's not working. or I have missunderstood

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the dynamic_month variable on the PHP side, but using it in Javascript; you'll need to replace the:

```
labels: {{ dynamic_month }},
```

With

```
labels: {<?php echo $dynamic_month ?>},
```

HTH