# Button not leading to desired location

Tags: php, html

Inside of my  tags I have an echo statement which in it has the following line:

```
"<button style='onclick='window.location.href='https://www.google.com''>Go to Google</button>"
```

my understanding is that this should make it so that t would bring you to whatever link is in the onclick argument. My button however is not going anywhere when I click it

Comment: inside the `onclick` you can only run javascript functions, not `window.location.href`

Comment: @RamondeVries That's [not true](https://jsfiddle.net/k7pmc61g/). You can call `window.location.href` in `onClick`event even if it's not best practice.

Comment: @Jax-p did they change that recently? i though it wasn't possible back when i learned coding

Comment: @RamondeVries I'm not sure - it might depends on script policies on each site.

Comment: How is this a "php" question? There isn't really anything showing us how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

1st problem: You have `onclick` event inside of `style` which is wrong. These are 2 separate attributes. Use only `onclick`.

2nd problem: You have same quotation marks for all strings (inside/outside). You have to use different for inner arguments.

Valid solution:

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com'">Go to Google</button>
```

Btw. I would rather use `<a>` instead of `<button/>`

Comment: The problem is that this whole thing is inside a php echo statement. That means the whole line has to be inside of ""s and when I keep nesting quatation marks inside of each other it starts to screw it all up

Comment: @GabeS. Use a backslash to escape quotation marks. [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for

EDIT: edited to fit inside php echo,

```js
function gotoPage(link){
window.location.href = "" +link;
}
```

```html
$link = "hoi";
echo "<button onclick='gotoPage(".$link.")'>Go to Google</button>";
```

Comment: When you put ""s at the front and end of that statement it cancels out the .$link. part. That is the issue I am having

Comment: you made the `echo` like this right?: `echo "button link in here"`

Comment: Yes. It is linking the first quotation mark with the first quote in the gotoPage argument. And the last quotation mark with the second quote in the gotoPage argument

Comment: my bad, im changing the anwser once more

Comment: please try this @GabeS.