# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hidden' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the html line

```
<input type="hidden" name="64fe437df7ac92d258ecfc8b46970ffc" value="1" /></form>
```

And i want to get this **64fe437df7ac92d258ecfc8b46970ffc** using preg_match

```
$url = "http://www.ugodambrosi.it/index.php?option=com_users&view=registration";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match("/<input type="hidden" name="(.*?)" value="1"/", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But why the result is

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hidden' (T_STRING) in on line 10
```

Comment: dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: You are not escaping the `"`s.

Comment: A good editor with syntax high-lighting (or just looking at the code snippet here on SO) should have helped spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/<input type='hidden' name='(.*?)' value='1'/", $result, $matches);
```

The input field is not closing because of the double-quotes. You can change it to single quotes.

Comment: Why have you changed double quotes into single? The original input line has double quotes, (re)read the question.