# javascript function didn't work at php echo

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

hello guys can u help me i want to echo my button but seems like my JS onclick function can't work

```
 echo "<th><button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="pindah('<?php echo $row->id ; ?>')">Detail Laptop &nbsp;<span class="fa fa-info"></span></button></th>";
```

Comment: Do you know how to escape quotation marks ? You may refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As stated by others already) You need to use the correct quotes. And concatenate your value instead of using `<?php echo...` when you already use `echo` to output:

```
echo '<th><button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pindah(' . $row->id . ')">Detail Laptop &nbsp;<span class="fa fa-info"></span></button></th>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes as the php statement is not completely error-free. Also please have a look at the below link for more details.

Link: [echo and print in PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp)

```
 echo "<th><button id=\"btnPrint\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary \" onclick=\"pindah('<?php echo $row->id ; ?>')\">Detail Laptop &nbsp;<span class=\"fa fa-info\"></span></button></th>";
```

Answer (score -3):

It will not work. JS is a client side scripting language. we cannot execute php code in javascript. please change your code in such a way it will do a post back on click or will make AJAX request on click.

Comment: OPs code will work though. PHP outputs given string and "only" sets a parameter for a JS function