# how to wriite php tag inside print or echo value

Tags: php

i want to hide an iframe for direct access.

and this code works fine

```
<?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('~mysite\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) {
print ('<iframe src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/" 
scrolling="no" width="622" height="350" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen</iframe>">');
} ?>
```

but when i try to add `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>`  in iframe url

```
<?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('~mysite\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) {
print ('<iframe src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" 
scrolling="no" width="622" height="350" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen</iframe>">');
} ?>
```

i got an error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in /www/wwwroot/domain.com/index.php on line 4
```

any solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can't nest  tags. You're trying to include a PHP echo statement within a print statement, which is incorrect.

You can solve this problem by concatenating the variable to the string, or use double quotes ("") and include the variable directly. Here's an example of both approaches:

**Concatenation method:**

```
<?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('~mysite\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) {
    print ('<iframe src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/' . $_GET['id'] . '" scrolling="no" width="622" height="350" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
?>
```

**Double quotes method:**

```
<?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('~mysite\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) {
    print ("<iframe src='https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/{$_GET['id']}' scrolling='no' width='622' height='350' frameborder='no' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
}
?>
```

note that you should sanitize $_GET['id'] before using it to avoid XSS attacks or other potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: the correct way to add multiple sites as reffering domains in below line 

`  <?php $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~site1\\.com$~' | '~site2\\.com$~' | '~site3\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) `

or we can add 

`  <?php $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; if (preg_match('~site1\\.com$~' * '~site2\\.com$~' * '~site3\\.com$~', parse_url($referrer, PHP_URL_HOST))) `